# Why does it take up to several minutes to clean a listening TCP port after a program dies?

Tags: networking, tcp, resources

If I kill a program that is listening on a TCP port, it takes up to several minutes until the port is reclaimed by the system and usable again. I've seen several Q/A mentioning this phenomenon, but without an explanation. Why does that happen, why doesn't the system reclaim the port right away? Does it also happen on another systems, such as Windows or Mac?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The idea behind this is to ensure you don't receive packets targeted for the previous program listening on that port. This `TIME_WAIT` state is defined in [RFC793](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) as two times the maximum segment lifetime.

I don't know about other Operating Systems but I assume that all of these have some kind of similar behavior.

A workaround for this problem is to set [`SO_REUSEADDR`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html#NOTES) on the socket which should ignore the `TIME_WAIT` state.

Comment: Checking my trusty TCP state diagram, I can see that the TIME_WAIT is the last state of a socket and generally persists for 2MSL - which is twice the maximum segment lifetime.  The spec (RFC793) states this as 2 minutes, giving 4 minutes in total.  This allows enough time for any requests and replies still "in flight" to be processed and land up at the right program - or to be discarded if the socket is in TIME_WAIT.

Comment: I can confirm that this happens in Windows too.

Comment: Additional Dig on this subject https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html